# Mailcore2: Distingue between thread email with single email on Gmail

Tags: mailcore2

I am using mailcore2 lib to build the app on iOS. I am trying to distingue between  thread email with single email on Gmail. The purpose is display thread icon for thread email and load all the email in the thread in background.

I fetch message from gmail and have an array of object MCOIMAPMessage. I check the "references" of MCOMessageHeader from MCOIMAPMessage.header

```
    /** References field. It's an array of message-ids.*/
    @property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * /* NSString */ references;
```

If thread the "references" have some info as

```
  message.header.references = (
       "CAH-THaOHPRJ=OZMrhZmFy=7s=sK4HC8TJ+a25UZ9fCcOdcVZ6g@mail.gmail.com",
       "CABK6ehzuV18YgoGJvd4Dabch95rmYFLrHhPp_NNvCYAJS0jrmg@mail.gmail.com",
       "CAH-THaPTJAK_QPQkexLgRO92DctjTtqexfdkXxQK0_g_oPexKQ@mail.gmail.com",
       "CABK6ehyFiQ4j8PmNNyg3bKOJNWS_JsF0BBpmZtGZH35kLFZukQ@mail.gmail.com",
       "CAH-THaPv0-RH-da2F5QH7oN21+jCDCRUYBUcH3Fi0mJJyCPoGQ@mail.gmail.com"
  )
```

if single message it will be nil.

Please help to correct or show me the proper way to identify between thread email vs single email.

It is great if we can get the info about how many email in the thread so that we can display the number as gmail app.

Great appreciate mailcore2 team.

Comment: You can fetch Gmail Thread IDs.

Comment: Thank you. I did as you mention but I wonder do we have another way without call extra fetch

Comment: You should be able to do that without any extra fetch.

Comment: It is great if you can give me example. Thanks

Comment: @DinhViêtHoà, can you give me the example or instruction how to do that without any extra fetch. Thanks